# Email and password getting printed on wrong form

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a page where there is a signup form. That signup form is having input fields

1. Email
2. Name
3. Mobile Number
4. Password

There is also a login button, in which I open a new page(same domain) inside a modal(in an iframe).

This modal has my login UI.

Now user enters username and password, upon submit Chrome ask to remember credentials. Upon clicking remember my application logs in to my home page.

So far things work as expected.

Now when I logout from the app, I am redirected to my signup form. However my signup form's email and password comes pre-filled with previous login that I click to remember.

This happens only in chrome but not in Firefox and Safari.

Comment: Have u cleared your cache?

Comment: I tried hard reload and clear cache, but it didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Try using `autocomplete="false` that should stop it unless something has changed.

Comment: Do you have link to your site?

Comment: Oh man, it was autocomplete="off" not false, was scratching my head for a while now. However thanks for pointing in right direction.